# How to apply transformer plugin after Ingress serviceName is updated?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kustomize transformer plugin that reads the value of serviceName in Ingress spec/rules/*/http/paths/0/backend/serviceName. The intent of the plugin is to update the host entries in the Ingress with the final serviceName after nameSuffix/namePrefix has been applied.

The plugins reads from stdin, but the state of the yaml isn't what I expected. The names of the Service and the Ingress have the nameSuffix/namePrefix applied, but the value of serviceName in the Ingress is still the raw service name. I verified this by dumping the Ingress yaml when the plugin executes. After the plugin runs, the final output does have the updated serviceName (with prefix/suffix). So something is running after the plugin that does the updating.

How do I configure the plugin so that it runs after the serviceName in the Ingress has been updated?

Answer (score 2):

According to this example: [Transformer Configs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/transformerconfigs)

`namePrefix` and `nameSuffix` have reference only:

```
 namePrefix:
- path: metadata/name
```

If you want to include `serviceName` to the `nameReference`, you can create, for example, a `kustomize-config.yml` file with the content:

```
nameReference:
- kind: ServiceName
  fieldSpecs:
  - path: spec/rules/*/http/paths/0/backend/serviceName
    kind: Ingress
```

Then, on your `kustomization.yml` you need to reference it:

```
configurations:
- kustomize-config.yml
```

Next time you run `kubectl kustomize .` or `kustomize build .`, you may see both Prefix and Suffix reflect also to `serviceName`